# Example of how to customize UIActivityViewController share menu?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

Is there an example of how to customize `UIActivityViewController` share menu with my own icon and `IBAction`?

I have seen this...

```
- (id)initWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems applicationActivities:(NSArray *)applicationActivities;
```

but I have not gotten it to work yet.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766300/how-can-i-create-a-custom-uiactivity-and-uiactivityprovider-in-ios-6][1] [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766300/how-can-i-create-a-custom-uiactivity-and-uiactivityprovider-in-ios-6 This Shows exactly how to do it, in a little while I was post a Basic share app with only one button and the code.

Comment: I don't understand, do you still need this question answered?

Comment: Someone else answered it in another question

Answer (score 8):

You first need to subclass `UIActivity`.

Then you need to override certain methods, including `activityImage` for setting the icon and `performActivity` for performing the action (what you call "IBAction" in your question).

If instead of performing the action silently, you first need further user interaction and info for your custom activity (e.g., like the Twitter post for the standard UIActivity), you should override `activityViewController` rather than `performActivity`.

After you have subclassed `UIActivity` (as, e.g, `MyActivity`), you should create an instance of `MyActivity` and make it an element of the `applicationActivities` array that you pass to `initWithActivityItems:applicationActivities:`.

Have a look at [the documentation for UIActivity](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for exactly what you need to override when subclassing and for icon requirements.

Hope this helps a little.