# Make custom item in UIActivityViewController icon colorful?

Tags: ios6, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

I follow the steps in [How can I create a custom UIActivity in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766300/how-can-i-create-a-custom-uiactivity-and-uiactivityprovider-in-ios-6) It works as expected. It looks like iOS force a metallic look&feel for all custom icons as well as its own "Bookmark", "Print", etc. Anyway to make my icon colorful?

Answer (score 2):

As of iOS 6, it is not possible to do this.

All color data for the `UIImage` that is returned by `UIActivity`'s `activityImage` method will be ignored.

Comment: Is this still the same in iOS7?

Comment: @SlavcoPetkovski still the same on iOS 9

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 10, set the `activityCategory` class property to .share.  This will cause the activity icon to appear in color in the top row of the UIActivityViewController.

In your UIActivity subclass:

In iOS 10, set the `activityCategory` class property to .share.  This will cause the activity icon to appear in color in the top row of the UIActivityViewController.

In your UIActivity subclass:

```
class MyCustomActivity: UIActivity
{
    ...

    override open class var activityCategory: UIActivityCategory
    {
        get
        {
            return UIActivityCategory.share;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```