# UIActivityViewController - Upload Youtube Video

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, youtube

I have a `UIActivityViewController` I'm using to share a video, I'm passing an `NSString` of text and a `NSUrl` that points to a local mp4 video file.

Sharing already works for email, message, photo album, etc. How can I upload my video to Youtube as well?

Apple does this in the default Photos and Camera app if you try it there. Can I do it in my app as well?

Comment: I'm asking about `UIActivityViewController` which the Photos and Camera app uses to upload to Youtube.

Comment: I know, and that post addresses the "How can I upload my video to Youtube as well?" bit.

Comment: I don't think this counts as a duplicate though.  I'm asking about an API Apple has for sharing that could potentially be a private API in the current version of iOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple only *share* some of the `UIActivity` that it uses in it's applications. That's likely because some are part of iOS while other are parts of the applications (different teams).

OTOH it's quite easy to add your own `UIActivity` to your application, e.g. see my [AirPlay](https://github.com/spouliot/airplay/blob/master/Poupou.AirPlay/UIAirPlayActivity.cs) `UIActivity` that comes with a [sample](https://github.com/spouliot/airplay/tree/master/airpic-ios).

So if you can find a .NET YouTube client library then you *should* only need a bit of glue to connect them.

Comment: Great, I think we will go this route. I had already found a C# example of uploading videos to YouTube. Hopefully it will compile for MonoTouch without much work.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as per [UIActivity class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011974-CH1-SW13) it is not included in iOS 6 (well, at least not in the public API).

You'll probably have to create your own UIActivity (just like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766300/how-can-i-create-a-custom-uiactivity-and-uiactivityprovider-in-ios-6)) and implement the youtube upload yourself.

Or hopefully there is a ready-made library that does so.

Comment: Afraid of that. If no one else chimes in, I'll mark you as the answer in a day or two.

Comment: Keeping fingers crossed. This might also help: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/. It's the newer version of the gdata library, that was often referenced in other discussions about this (newer in terms of the API version at least).