# UIActivity with custom image

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios6, uiactivity

Is there any way to made UIActivity to display custom images?
By default it created metal-style-icons. Is there any way to disable it?

Secondly, can I use UIActivity instead of UIActionSheet? Are there any guidelines when it should (not) be used?

Comment: UIActivity /// ?? uiactivityindicator ??

Comment: @iPatel [`UIActivity`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/Reference/Reference.html) are the activities in the iOS 6 social share dialog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom `UIActivity` only displays grayscale images. Yes, you can use `UIActivityViewController` instead of `UIActionSheet`, but you have to create every `UIActivity` for that by yourself. Here is the nice way to create your own `UIActivity`: [How can I create a custom UIActivity and UIActivityProvider in iOS 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766300/how-can-i-create-a-custom-uiactivity-and-uiactivityprovider-in-ios-6)

When and how to use `UIActivity` depends on yourself.
Good Luck!