# if i can share content of other app to my app

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

using uiactivity ,i can share  content of my app to Facebook,twitter,email.

```
UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]   initWithActivityItems:activityItems
                                                                                  applicationActivities:activities];
```

so i want to add my custom uiactivity,when user using UIActivityViewController at other app,my app can appear on the  UIActivityViewController like Facebook,so it can share content to my app?

if apple allow me to do this,if yes,how to do?can you give some advice

edit: i think this is not repeat question。my question: i want to my app like Facebook,twitter can show at other developer app,if it used UIActivityViewController. if you cannot understand my question,you can ask me,i can give detail describe.sorry for my english

Comment: means want to share content on `facebook` using `iOS App` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a custom UIActivity and UIActivityProvider in iOS 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766300/how-can-i-create-a-custom-uiactivity-and-uiactivityprovider-in-ios-6)

Comment: i want to using iOS App share content to my app,i want to my app appear at the UIActivityViewController of other app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766300/how-can-i-create-a-custom-uiactivity-and-uiactivityprovider-in-ios-6 is add custom uiactivity of  my app. the custom uiactivity not appear other develop app.

Comment: in  other words,i want to my app like Facebook,twitter,message,can always show at other develop app

Comment: Did you check this tutorial? [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-how-to-build-a-simple-action-extension--cms-22794)