# Am I understanding the UIActivityViewController wrong?

Tags: ios, sharing, uiactivityviewcontroller

from my opinion, I can pass text, images etc. to the UIActivityViewController and it will show exactly these apps, that can handle the file types I´m passing in. But it isn´t behaving like that! It´s just showing the standard apps Mail, Messages, Twitter, Facebook and Copy. These are not changing at all, regardless of what I´m passing to UIActivityViewController.
I read that you have to subclass UIActivity to be able to support other Apps, but this renders the whole concept useless to me, as I have to know, which apps could do what.

Am I the only one that´s frustrated with this? Or am I just doing something wrong?

And to have some code:

```
NSArray *items = @[@"sometext", @"some longer text", [NSURL urlWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/"]];

controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];
```

Expected: to have apps like Evernote, Instagram etc. in the ActivityViewController

Comment: Go to https://bugreport.apple.com and file a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561530/if-i-can-share-content-of-other-app-to-my-app). It doesn't seem anyone has an answer for either of them. Seems like if you create a `UIActivity`, you can only use it in your app within your own `UIActivityViewController`.