# How to create share button in iOS 9?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, uiactivityviewcontroller

In my app i want to create a share button with WhatsApp,Facebook,Twitter,Mail like this.

Here is my code

```
-(IBAction)share:(id)sender
{
NSString *shareText = @"Hi This is a Reward Game App";
NSArray *itemsToShare = @[shareText];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,UIActivityTypePostToTwitter,UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,UIActivityTypeMail,UIActivityTypeMessage,UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I'm writing this code my simulator display like this,

[image]

It shows only mail and facebook icons, i want whatsup icon message like this nore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add custom buttons to UIActivityViewController?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20029520/how-to-add-custom-buttons-to-uiactivityviewcontroller)

Comment: You can't see all application in simulator. You have to run your app in device

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)shareAction:(id)sender
 {    
        NSArray* sharedObjects=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"sharecontent",  nil];
        UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:sharedObjects applicationActivities:nil];
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
        [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2**

```
func shareMessage(message: String, link: String) {
    if let link = NSURL(string: link) {
        let objectsToShare = [message, link] as [Any]
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
        present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

call this function :

```
shareMessage(message: "Hello World!", link: "https://www.apple.com/")
```

output :

[image]

Comment: That's not answering OP's question. He would like to show other App's actions, such as WhatsApp, which is only possible to be shown in actual device.

Answer (score 0):

swift 4.2
That code working now

```
        let text = "race"
        let url = "https://medium.com/@javedmultani16/share-text-image-and-url-by-using-uiactivityviewcontroller-in-swift-4eb253e43d55"
        let shareAll = [text, url] as [Any]
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareAll, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.