# Social sharing in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm writing a function that when a button is clicked makes a screenshot, and then lets you share this photo on Twitter, Instagram and Facebook.
 So I have a function for all apps EXCEPT Instagram:

```
func socialShare(sharingText: String?, sharingImage: UIImage?) {
    var sharingItems = [AnyObject]()

    if let text = sharingText {
        sharingItems.append(text as AnyObject)
    }
    if let image = sharingImage {
        sharingItems.append(image)
    }
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: sharingItems, applicationActivities: nil)

    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.addToReadingList, UIActivityType.print, UIActivityType.assignToContact, UIActivityType.copyToPasteboard]

    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And also function for Instagram sharing:

```
var docController: UIDocumentInteractionController!

func documentsDirectory() -> String {
    return NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
}

func postImageToInstagram(sharingImage: UIImage?) {



    let instagram = URL(string: "instagram://app")!


    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagram) {


        let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory())

        let fullPath = imageURL.appendingPathComponent("instagram.igo")

        do {
            try UIImagePNGRepresentation(sharingImage!)!.write(to: fullPath)

            let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

            let igImageHookFile = URL(string: "file://\(fullPath)")

            docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: igImageHookFile!)

            docController.uti = "com.instagram.photo"
            docController.presentOpenInMenu(from: rect, in: self.view, animated: true)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }  
    }
    else {
        print("Instagram not installed")
    }

}
```

How I can use it together? Because they work only separately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that it is slightly annoying that Instagram is not included in the default `UIActivityViewController` activities. But that does not mean that you can't add your own `UIActivity` for Instagram and the logic you already have to post to Instagram in your already created method. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20029778/3911918) post from SO on how to create your own `UIActivity`s. It even includes a link to a fancy GitHub repo that has custom `UIActivity`s for most of the left out social services, including Instagram.

Comment: I noticed that Instagram does appear in the sharing options if the `activityItems` given to `UIActivityViewController` contains only a single `UIImage` and not text.