# How to Share a Video from my app to YouTube and Instagram Apps using UIActivityViewController in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, xcode5, uiactivityviewcontroller

I want to share **videos** from my application into **youtube** and **instagram** using UIActivityViewController. But i got output like below mentioned image.

[image]

But my Expectation is, to add Youtube and Instagram apps into this UIActivityViewController for **Videos**. Like below mentioned image. This image taken from device Photo album.

[image]

My Code is:

```
- (IBAction)ShareVideo:(id)sender
{
    NSString *mySubject=@"Video Sharing ";
    NSString *textLocationA=@"India";
    NSString *textObject = @"Video Sharing Test";
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:movieURL]; //movieURL contains the video taken from photoAlbum

    NSArray *objectsToShare = @[mySubject,textLocationA,textObject,videoData,movieURL];

    UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

    // Exclude all activities except AirDrop.
    NSArray *excludedActivities = @[UIActivityTypePostToTwitter, UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,
                                    UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                    UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypeMail,
                                    UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                    UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                    UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                    UIActivityTypePostToVimeo, UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo];
    controller.excludedActivityTypes = excludedActivities;

    //-- define the activity view completion handler
    controller.completionHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed){
        NSLog(@"Activity Type selected: %@", activityType);
        if (completed) {
            NSLog(@"Selected activity was performed.");
        } else {
            if (activityType == NULL) {
                NSLog(@"User dismissed the view controller without making a selection.");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Activity was not performed.");
            }
        }
    };

    //-- define activity to be excluded (if any)
    controller.excludedActivityTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, nil];
    [controller setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
        if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook]) {
            if (completed)
            {
                NSLog(@"facebook");

            }

        }
        else if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll]) {
            if (completed)
            {
                NSLog(@"Video Saved");
            }
        }

        else if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter]) {
            if (completed)
            {
                NSLog(@"twittter");
            }

        }
    }];

    // Present the controller
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Please give me some idea to handle this process.

Comment: @Kramnik0 - see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20628620/youtube-and-uiactivityview-on-ios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an API for it, check it out:

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Uploading_Videos

Answer (score 3):

To add YouTube in UIActivityViewController, you have to custom the UIActivityViewController by yourself. Please refer [How can I create a custom UIActivity in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766300/how-can-i-create-a-custom-uiactivity-in-ios) I added a custom Youtube icon in the UIActivityViewController and enable to upload video to Youtube.

For how to upload video to YouTube, you can read this https://nsrover.wordpress.com/2014/04/23/youtube-api-on-ios/ I tested it. It works.

Answer (score 2):

1. You have to add your own custom UIActivity for youtube: [How can I create a custom UIActivity in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766300/how-can-i-create-a-custom-uiactivity-in-ios-6)
2. Add share dialog. You can use this lib: https://github.com/romaonthego/REComposeViewController
3. Use API for sharing. Thanks @UserAwesome : http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Uploading_Videos

OR

You can try to find existing component for it. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. wait i will check and let u know.

Comment: @Sabs searching github and others is your way then