# List developer app in gallery settings

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How do i make my sample app get listed in settings(or more) screen in gallery?
Like, twitter app, facebook app. 
I want user to select few photos and then when he click on "more button" in bottom left, i would like to list my app there so that user can access from there itself.

I played around with permissions and now app gets listed in settings->privacy settings->Photos

Comment: Im new to iOS, It would be nice if people can tell me what is wrong with my question, than voting for close.

Comment: I suggest you to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766300/how-can-i-create-a-custom-uiactivity-in-ios-6-7/12766330#12766330)