# Is it possible share a link with text to Linkedin with UIActivityViewController?

Tags: swift, linkedin-api, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'd like to share a link + text to Linkedin with a UIActivityViewController but my code don't works :( I see Facebook and Twitter but not Linkedin

```
    let url: NSURL =  NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")!
    let text: String = "Test Linkedin"

    let items: [AnyObject] = [url, text]

    let activityViewController: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.setValue("Test", forKey: "subject")
    self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If I set only the url I see Linkedin in my options. Where is the problem? I see that Safari Sharing works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple does not provide an activity for LinkedIn. If you want to share text and a link with the UIActivityViewController, you need to create your own UIActivity. See the documentation here :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/index.html

You can also look at this SO post that will show you how to create your custom one (in Objective-C)

[How can I create a custom UIActivity in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766300/how-can-i-create-a-custom-uiactivity-in-ios-6-7)