# How to get the share sheet like dropbox

Tags: ios

Can someone tell me how to get a document share sheet like dropbox has?

I tried UIDocumentInterActionController and UIActivityController but don't know how to add the "Open-in..." button.

It looks like this:
[image: Dropbox document share sheet options]

Comment: You can see how to create a custom UIActivity here
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12766330/1870192

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Open In..." seems to be a custom *UIActivity* (thus presented by an *UIActivityViewController*), which simply presents a *UIDocumentInteractionController* when selected.