# Is there a way to control which activity types must be shown in activity view controller?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am getting an array of activity types from server side to be shown in my activity view controller. I only see a method to to exclude items. But no way to say I want to show only a specific set of apps on the activity view. It will be great if there is a method that will tell me what apps are populated  on activity view. That way I can compare and exclude the items I dont want.

Comment: In short no. To Apple excluding is the same as only show specific ones. You could subclass and make your own UIAcivity initwithactivity based on the content

Comment: Any example on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

In activity View controller the apps are listed based on the items that u are initializing. You can only exclude apps like Facebook twitter Vimeo etc which are logged in through device settings app. Apps that are installed on device which support share extension are listed in activity view controller cannot be excluded.If you provide photo as activity item to share then Facebook, twitter, and other photo sharing apps that are installed on device  will be listed. If you provide video as activity item to share then Facebook, Vimeo and other video sharing apps like Vine etc will be listed where Vine is installed app on phone which cannot be excluded.
If you want to add your own share site then you can go for Custom UI Activty View Controller. Where you have to subclass UIActivity.Following link might help you [How can I create a custom UIActivity in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766300/how-can-i-create-a-custom-uiactivity-in-ios-6-7).