# gmail subject is same as gmail body content in ios

Tags: gmail, message, subject

I am using UIActivityController to share the information in mail,facebook,gmail. But in gmail my message body becomes the message subject.
Plz tell what will i do to remove this.

Thank you

Comment: Please share your code. It's impossible to help you without any more details.

Comment: same issue with me...Have you go the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass NSUrl as activityItems array to avoid copying body content to subject.
I provided details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59160455/2858285).