# UIActivityViewController Gmail Share subject and body going Same

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, gmail, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am sharing Some content via `UIActivityController`.

It is working fine for other Options.

I am able to get `subject` and `body` in Default Mail App.

But when I use to share the content with `gmail` then my `Subject` of the mail is gone and I am getting `Body` content in Gmail `Subject's` section:

Here is my code:

```
    NSString *body = @"I am Body";
NSString *tagLine = @"I am Subject";

   NSArray *objectToShare = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:body, nil];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectToShare applicationActivities:nil];

[activityVC setValue:tagLine forKey:@"subject"];

NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                               UIActivityTypePrint,
                               UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                               UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                               UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                               UIActivityTypePostToVimeo];

activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

For better Picture Here is the screenshot:

With Default App:

[image]

With Gmail:
    [image]

I also tried different answers on SO. But none of them works.

Comment: Got any solution for this issue, i am also getting same issue ?

Comment: @San007 no bro. Not get any solution.

Comment: @RahulMishra Any new here ?

Comment: @Yossi No Yossi Didn't found any solution :(

Comment: @RahulMishra It's looks like Gmail's bug. I implemented UIActivityItemProvider that using UIActivityItemSource protocol, which is a better way to handle it, and still it not helps

Comment: More than 2 years and still the same issue with Gmail and Google Inbox. Any news out there?

Comment: @FelipePlets no news about this bug. Still struggling to get a finest solution.

Comment: I am seeing this same issue. It's 2017 already, no solution yet?

Comment: Created and issue in google product forums related to this ticket, please upvote: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/UJJx4BcRJiU;context-place=forum/gmail

Comment: @brisky upvoted... lets c when this is fixed :)

Comment: It's almost 2018, no solution yet? :)

Comment: I've got this issue as well. The entire message body is showing up in the Subject line.

Comment: @Santosh Unfortunatley there is not solution for this yet.

Comment: this is common problem with all 3rd party email clients I know (Google, Yahoo, Outlook). There is nothing you can do.

Comment: It is still not fixed in 2018. and there's no way we can stop sharing to email clients.

Comment: Hi guys, I have open an issue on Gmail's official discussion forum. If you want to fix this let's show your support by commenting / or you may create another issue. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/9JRqN0rVxYo;context-place=forum/gmail

Comment: Dude! This guy found how they do it on Reddit for iOS (and I noticed that Slack also does it) https://stackoverflow.com/a/51451433/1272263 They add a lot of empty spaces in the beginning of the body text! Here is a screenshot of it. Mail app on the left and Gmail on the right: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThsY1.jpg Still a hack but it works

Answer (score 5):

At the time of writing this, Google doesn't allow setting the subject of email. People have reported it as a bug multiple times, and it seems this feature is still not supported.

Looking at other Google-owned products, and trying to share some contents via Gmail, you will see that the Gmail shared activity doesn't have the subject (e.g Google Chrome), or it's the same as the email's body (Google Translator), while if you share them to the normal app it appears that some of them have a subject. So even Google products have the same behaviour.

If you use a breakpoint inside the `subjectForActivityType` function you will realise that the Gmail activity won't hit the breakpoint while default mail and other activities will attempt to read the subject.

```
@implementation EmailItemProvider

- (id)activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController {
    return _body;
}

- (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType {
    return _body;
}

- (NSString *)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController subjectForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType {
    return _subject;
}
```

Comment: I know that everyone have reported it as a bug but I've saw today that Reddit managed to take the "Subject" out in their app. I've posted more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56646569/1272263