# To Show Mail apps in UIActivityController in Swift - UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiactivitycontroller

I'm new to iOS App Development. Is it possible to show only the Mail apps which was installed in iPhone in the UIActivityController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly. There's no way to specify the kind of apps you want to show in there. However, there is a way using which you can specify the type of services you wish to exclude.

[`UIActivityViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller) has a property [`excludedActivityTypes`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller/1622009-excludedactivitytypes). You can exclude all other [types of activities](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivity/activitytype) except [`mail`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivity/activitytype/1620669-mail)

You should be able to narrow the list of apps down quite a bit.

Comment: It is possible to give Email To address and Subject Text ???

Comment: I did a little bit of searching and found this (you should find all the information that you need in this question discussion and the other linked questions): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34264751/uiactivityviewcontroller-gmail-share-subject-and-body-going-same