# I want to share on gmail using UIActivityViewController without custom activity

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I browse many stack overflow links for share on gmail using `UIActivityViewController`. All are saying make custom `UIACtivy` , but that option will make new custom activity , I don't want that. The code for gmail share which is given [UIActivityViewController not showing body text in gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28951113/uiactivityviewcontroller-not-showing-body-text-in-gmail) is using custom activity. I have check IMDb application, In it sharing using `UIActivityViewController` is done and its working perfectly fine with gmail without custom activity . Please provide me solution for swift to share on gmail using `UIActivityViewController` without creating custom activity. If this is not possible without custom activity , can you give me reason for that?Please provide solution for swift only as many time happens code for objective-c doesn't work with swift.

Comment: Hi,Have you got any solution for this ?