# How to show/add Gmail and Yahoo mail apps through UIActivityViewController in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a requirement to share some content through Message, Mail, Facebook, Twitter, Whatsapp, Gmail and Yahoo mail apps from my application as shown in below screen. So I've implemented `UIActivityViewController` to show share view with apps but Gmail and Yahoo apps are not being added to share view. Whatsapp is being added once I installed the app but not Gmail and Yahoo apps. Do we have to do any settings or have to implement a custom `UIActivity` class for Gmail and Yahoo apps. Please help me on it.

[image]

Comment: First check if Gmail and Yahoo! are installed in your device or not

Comment: I installed Gmail and Yahoo mail apps in my device. But those are not listing in UIActivityViewController.

Comment: Hope you didn't exclude those in `excludedActivityTypes`. You can create custom activity though. Check answer below.

Answer (score 0):

First check if Gmail and Yahoo! are installed in your device or not. If still it doesn't show them, then try to create custom UIActivity.

Please check these links:
[Custom UIActivity for Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28951113/uiactivityviewcontroller-not-showing-body-text-in-gmail#28952690) and
[Custom UIActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766300/how-can-i-create-a-custom-uiactivity-in-ios/12766330#12766330)

Hope these will help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install theses apps in your device. Only Installed apps show in "UIActivityViewController".

Comment: I installed Gmail and Yahoo mail apps in my device. But those are not listing in UIActivityViewController.