# (Objective C) Open default Apple Mail app, Yahoo Mail or Safari without compose screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, xcode8

I have a button that when it is clicked, It will let us choose between default mail app, yahoo mail and Safari to read inbox. 
Currently i'm using:

```
NSURL* mailURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto:abc@gmail.com&subject=My%20Subject%20Line&body=Hello%20Email!"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: mailURL];
```

This code always open the compose screen. I don't want it be shown. I just want to open inbox or just only open the mail app. How can I implement that? 
Thank you very much!

**UPDATE**

I know how to open app without compose screen now.

If you want to open default mail app, use:

```
NSURL* mailURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"message://"];
```

If you want to open Gmail, use:

```
NSString *gmailUrl = @"googlegmail://";
```

Now the problem is: How to show a dialog to choose between them

[Like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEP6A.png)

Comment: so you don' t want compose mail or you want compose option in mail app only ?

Comment: I dont want to compose mail, I just want to choose one of them to check mail @CodeChanger

Comment: Check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40910825/how-to-show-add-gmail-and-yahoo-mail-apps-through-uiactivityviewcontroller-in-io

Comment: where u tried this simulator or device

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik im testing on real device (Iphone 6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be below code can help:

```
NSURL* mailURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"message://"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:mailURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:mailURL];
}
```

Reads more at: https://www.macstories.net/tutorials/ios-7-and-mail-message-urls/

Also check [Vladimir's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/137350/vladimir) answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29211632/5575752

Comment: Thank you, I'm checking on it