# UIActivityViewController customisation

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

My requirement is to add a label to `UIActivityViewController` and remove cancel button. Also I want to remove items separator. How can I achieve this. Also, I am not sure if this is the right way. I have created subclass of `UIActivityViewController` as under:

```
@interface SampleActivityViewController : UIActivityViewController

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to create your own custom UIActivity
Have a [look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766300/how-can-i-create-a-custom-uiactivity-in-ios).

You can also have a look at this [project](https://github.com/shu223/UIActivityCollection) on github, basically is a collection of custom UIActivity for the most common services Instagram included.

Comment: This is not what i asked for.Thanks for your reply. What i need i to customise the sheet content along with cancel button.