# How to get all applicationActivities for an UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, ios6, uiactivityviewcontroller

How can I get a `NSArray` of all `applicationActivities` installed in the device?

```
- (id)initWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems applicationActivities:(NSArray *)applicationActivities;
```

I'd like to remove one or two items and show the rest of the full list.

Comment: Are you looking for [excludedActivityTypes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIActivityViewController/excludedActivityTypes) property of `UIActivityViewController`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719931/example-of-how-to-customize-uiactivityviewcontroller-share-menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how to get list of all `applicationActivities`. If you want to exclude some activity types, you can use `excludedActivityTypes` property of `UIActivityViewController`. As per [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIActivityViewController/excludedActivityTypes),

> This property contains an array of strings, each of which corresponds
>   to the value you would find in the activityType parameter of a
>   UIActivity object. Each string you specify indicates a service that
>   you do not want displayed to the user. You might exclude services that
>   you feel are not suitable for the content you are providing. For
>   example, you might not want to allow the user to print a specific
>   image. If the value of this property is nil, no services are excluded.
>
> This value of this property is nil by default.

Comment: This "answer" literally begins by saying "I don't know the answer."

Comment: To be fair, the question had two parts 1)get all applicationActivities 2)remove one or two activities. Since this answers second part and ohho selected that as the correct answer, I would say this is infact the correct answer to this question. So not sure why the above comment was made here.

Answer (score 1):

The activity strings are listed at the bottom of the documentation for UIActivity Class Reference [UIActivity.ActivityType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivity/activitytype).

They are listed as UIActivityTypePostToFacebook, UIActivityTypePostToTwitter, etc. These are actually strings defined in UIActivity.h.

Try this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", UIActivityTypePostToFacebook);
```

Then you can compare to these strings to display a message to the user specific to the activity type.